# Can not set debuggable flag in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-manifest

I try to accomplish [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjsC-lKUgM8) to learn debugging NDK apps, but when I set `android:debuggable="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml file the following error occurs:

> Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and
>   release builds to automatically assign one

How to solve it to be able to debug Teapot app?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse+ADT?

Comment: @MartinKonecny Eclipse+ADT+NDK+ANT. I didn't know about Android Studio which is based on Intelij. That should be a better environment. Can I just use Android Studio instead of Eclipse? Are they interchangeable or they use completely different tools and concepts?

Comment: broken youtube link...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See official doc for [SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html), Revision 8 (December 2010)

> Support for a true debug build. Developers no longer need to add the
>   `android:debuggable` attribute to the `<application>` tag in the manifest
>   — the build tools add the attribute automatically. In **Eclipse/ADT**, all
>   incremental builds are assumed to be debug builds, so the tools insert
>   `android:debuggable="true"`. When exporting a signed release build, the
>   tools do not add the attribute. In Ant, a ant debug command
>   automatically inserts the `android:debuggable="true"` attribute, while
>   ant release does not. If `android:debuggable="true"` is manually set,
>   then ant release will actually do a debug build, rather than a release
>   build.

**Update**

If you really want to disable checking for debuggable flag in Eclipse you should do next:

1. Go to the **Project Preferences**:
2. Select **Android Lint Preferences**
3. Find **HardcodedDebugMode** Id in **Security** section and select it
4. Change the value of **Severity** to **Warning** for example.
5. **Apply** and **Ok**.

*Screen for details:* [image]

Comment: The video says that I can do just `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_OPTIM=debug` and it will be equivalent to setting `android:debuggable="true"`, but, please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985558/error-package-cookbook-chapter3-is-not-debuggable-ndk-gdb

Comment: This is the answer. `debuggable=true` is automatically set each time until you do a release build

Comment: But I have tried as view suggests: didn't use `debuggable` but used `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_OPTIM=debug` to build. And as in the video, I press `Debug As->Android Native Application`. At first it was rebuilding without debug info (`gdbsetup, gdbserver`). Then I removed NDK path `Preferences->Android->NDK` so that it couldn't rebuild and just run `Debug As->...` and now I have another problem: `gdbserver output:   run-as: exec failed for lib/gdbserver Error:No such file or directory    Verify if the application was built with NDK_DEBUG=1

Comment: @Gary111 is it possible to disable Eclipse check of `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: I tried to find how to disable this checking after your question was asked. But I have found nothing yet.

Comment: Done the equivalent in Android Studio, error disappears from the editor, still throws an error when I try to compile it, won't let me build the app.

Comment: @Narek i'm getting same error `gdbserver output: run-as: exec failed for lib/gdbserver Error:No such file or directory Verify if the application was built with NDK_DEBUG=1` how did you solve that?