# Android NDK app not able to hit any breakpoint

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, java-native-interface

**I am using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjsC-lKUgM8 tutorial to try to debug a simple NDK app.** I have done everything as it is in the video except:

1. I am on OS X 10.9.3 instead of Windows.
2. I don't use `android:debuggable=true`(cause eclipse considers it as error) in AndroidManifest.xml instead I have set the NDK path from `Preferences->Android->NDK` and in `Project Properties -> C/C++ Build` unchecked `Use default build command` and set there `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_OPTIM=debug`.
3. I don't use `x86 emulator` but `Samsung Duos S` device with `Android 4.0.4`

But the breakpoiin that is used in the video in not being hit in my case. I am trying to debug a simple NDK test project already the 4th day. Have investigated lots of material:

1. Android Native Development Kit Cookbook
2. Bunch of forums and tutorials
3. Videos

But can not hit a single damn breakpoint. Please help if you could do this ever.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone ever get native code debugging to work, although I've known some smart people to try.  They all gave up and used printf debugging on C parts.

Comment: It somehow explains the 4th day of trying to hit a single breakpoint. But I still didn't give up. I still hope. :)

Comment: I have successfully debugged native code using ADB/GDB in Eclipse; so it is possible :-)  I documented this process in my company's internal Wiki.  It's LONG.  I'll try to remember to post it here tomorrow.

Comment: @bstar55 please do that.

Comment: IIRC `android:debuggable=true` is absolutely necessary. It permits running processes with uid of the application via `adb` and without that the debugger can't be attached.

Comment: @JanHudec please see my question here about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986724/can-not-set-debuggable-flag-in-androidmanifest-xml How to set that flag if Eclipse complains with an error? Should I turn off some checks and just ignore it? If yes, then how to do that?

Comment: @Narek:Hm, true, Eclipse should be doing it itself. Can you check whether you are building it in the way where it does?

Comment: @JanHudec sorry I don't understand what you want me to check.

Answer (score 5):

The following is an excerpt from an tutorial I wrote for our internal Android development team.  The bulk of which was derived from this blog: http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/

Important notes:

1. I use a Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) environment for my Android work.
2. I used the ADT Bundle for Linux, Build: v22.2.1-833290 (Eclipse IDE + Extras)
3. These steps are for debugging from a Java Activity into a JNI shared object.
4. I created test projects for this tutorial which won't be posted here, though references to those projects are present in the instructions that follow.  You'll need an existing Android Application Project as well as a JNI shared object that is being called by your Java code.

### Project Setup

3. **Enable Debugging.**

> Open AndroidManifest.xml, select the Application tab, and set **`Debuggable=true`**. This will make the application debuggable even when it's running on a device that's running in user mode.
> 4. **Build the Native Sources**. From the Terminal, enter the project directory and enter:

```
    ndk-build -B
```

You should see the following output:

> Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
> Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
> Compile++ thumb  : DebuggingTestJNI <= com_sample_test_DebuggingTestActivity.cpp
> StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
> SharedLibrary  : libDebuggingTestJNI.so
> Install        : libDebuggingTestJNI.so => libs/armeabi/libDebuggingTestJNI.so

8. **Clean the Project.** In the Eclipse menu strip, select Project→Clean. It is good to perform this step anytime you change/build your native sources. This step ensures that Eclipse will rebuild your .apk.

### Native Debug Setup

1. **Create Java Debug Configuration.** We need to create a debug configuration for stepping into Java source code.

> - In the Eclipse toolbar, you'll see a green bug. Click the little arrow next to the bug and select "Debug Configurations…".
> - Double-click "Android Application" in the tree structure on the left. This will create a template for a new Android Application Debug Configuration.
> - In the "Name:" field, name it "DebuggingTest Java Debug" to make sure you know this Configuration applies specifically to the DebuggingTest project, and targets your Java source.
> - Under "Project:", click the "Browse…" button and select DebuggingTest.
> - Click "Apply" to save your changes.
> - Click "Close".
> - In the Eclipse toolbar, click the little arrow next to the bug and select "Organize Favorites…".
> - Click "Add…"
> - Select "DebuggingTest Java Debug" and click "OK".

Your new debug configuration has now been created and added to your favorites. You can access your favorites by clicking the little arrow next to the bug in the toolbar. "DebuggingTest Java Debug" should be at the top of the list.

2. **Run ndk-gdb.**

> - In the Eclipse toolbar, click the little arrow next to the bug and select "DebuggingTest Java Debug". This will deploy and install the DebuggingTest.apk to your connected Android device and start the debugger.
> - Navigate to the DebuggingTest project directory in your Terminal and type the following:
>
>   `ndk-gdb`

**If the command succeeds, you should see the following:**

> GNU gdb 6.6
> Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
> welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
> Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
> There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
> This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-elf-linux".
> (no debugging symbols found)
> …

**If you forgot to start debugging the application before this step, you get the following:**

> **ERROR:** Could not extract PID of application on device/emulator.
> Are you sure the application is already started?
> Consider using --start or --launch= if not.
> If your Android.mk file is malformed or contains $(info) blocks, you get the following:
> cp: target `./obj/local/armeabi/gdb.setup' is not a directory /home/Dev/NDK/ndk-gdb: 639: cannot create start DebuggingTest/jni/Android.mk end DebuggingTest/jni/Android.mk ./obj/local/armeabi/gdb.setup: Directory nonexistent /home/Dev/NDK/ndk-gdb: 640: cannot create start DebuggingTest/jni/Android.mk end DebuggingTest/jni/Android.mk ./obj/local/armeabi/gdb.setup: Directory nonexistent start: invalid option: -x Try` start --help' for more information.

**If ndk-gdb is already running, you get the following:**

> **ERROR:** Another debug session running, Use --force to kill it.

**Resolve your ERRORs before continuing. ndk-gdb MUST run successfully.**

Running **`ndk-gdb`** does not only ensure us that we are doing everything right so far, but also creates **`app_process`**, **`gdb.setup`** and **`libc.so`** files in the obj/local/armeabi/ sub-directory of our project. Those files will be needed in later steps.

3. Stop Debugging.

> - In your Terminal, type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to stop ndk-gdb.
> - In Eclipse, select Run → Terminate.
>   4. Create C/C++ Debug Configuration. We need to create a debug configuration for stepping into C/C++ source code.
> - **In Eclipse**, click the little arrow next to the bug and select "Debug Configurations…".
> - Double-click "C/C++ Application" in the tree structure on the left. This will create a template for a new C/C++ Application Debug Configuration.
> - In the "Name:" field, name it "DebuggingTest C and CPP Debug" to make sure you know this Configuration applies specifically to the DebuggingTest project, and targets your C/C++ source.
> - **In the "Main" tab:**
> - Click "Browse…" on the "C/C++ Application:" field.
>   Navigate to "/home/Test/testing/DebuggingTest/obj/local/armeabi/app_process" and click "OK".
> - Click "Browse…" on the "Project:" field.
> - Select "DebuggingTest" and click "OK".
> - Check the "Disable auto build" box.
> - At the bottom of the form, you'll see "Using GDB (DSF) … - Select other…". Press the "Select other…" button.
> - In the pop-up, check the "Use configuration specific settings" box.
> - Select "Standard Create Process Launcher" in the list and press "OK".
> - **In the "Debugger" tab:**
> - Click the combo-box on the "Debugger:" field and select "gdbserver".
> - Uncheck the "Stop on startup at:" box.
> - **In the "Main" sub-tab:**
> - Click "Browse…" on the "GDB debugger:" field.
> - Navigate to "/home/Dev/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb" and click "OK".  **This debugger is distributed with the Android NDK**.
> - In the "GDB command file:" field, type "/home/Test/testing/DebuggingTest/obj/local/armeabi/gdb2.setup". The gdb2.setup file does not exist yet, but we'll create it shortly.
> - Check the "Use full file path to set breakpoints" box.
> - **In the "Connection" sub-tab:**
> - Set "Type:" to TCP
> - Set "Port number:" to 5039
> - Click "Apply" to save your changes.
> - Click "Close"
> - In the Eclipse toolbar, click the little arrow next to the bug and select "Organize Favorites…".
> - Click "Add…"
> - Select "DebuggingTest C and CPP Debug" and click "OK".

Your new debug configuration has now been created and added to your favorites. You can access your favorites by clicking the little arrow next to the bug in the toolbar. "DebuggingTest C and CPP Debug" should be at the top of the list.

4. **Create gdb2.setup.** Eclipse doesn't like the "target remote :5039" line in gdb setup file because it wants to enter this command internally (that is why you configured port 5039 in the previous step). Because the gdb.setup file is recreated by the NDK scripts, you have to copy it to the gdb2.setup and point Eclipse to the gdb2.setup file (which we did in the previous step).

> - In your File Explorer, navigate to "/home/Test/testing/DebuggingTest/obj/local/armeabi/".
> - Copy the "gdb.setup" file and then paste it into the same folder. The result should be a file named "gdb (copy).setup".
> - Rename "gdb (copy).setup" to "gdb2.setup".
> - Open gdb2.setup by double-clicking the file.
> - Replace "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi" with "set solib-search-path /home/Test/testing/DebuggingTest/obj/local/armeabi".
> - Replace "file ./obj/local/armeabi/app_process" with "file /home/Test/testing/DebuggingTest/obj/local/armeabi/app_process".
> - Remove the line that reads "target remote :5039".
> - Save and Close the file.
>   5. **Create ndk-gdb-eclipse.** One last Eclipse housekeeping item. Eclipse will run the gdb binary itself, so we have to remove the execution of gdb from ndk-gdb. We'll save the original content by doing another Copy-Paste-Rename.
> - In your File Explorer, navigate to "/home/Dev/NDK".
> - Copy the "ndk-gdb" file and then paste it into the same folder. The result should be a file named "ndk-gdb (copy)".
> - Rename "ndk-gdb (copy)" to "ndk-gdb-eclipse".
> - Open ndk-gdb-eclipse by doing a right-click → Open With Other Application …
> - Select Text Editor from the list of applications
> - In the file, locate the line that reads "$GDBCLIENT -x `native_path $GDBSETUP`" (probably at the very bottom) and comment it out by prefixing it with a "#" character.
> - Save and Close the file.

**When Debugging native sources within the Eclipse IDE**, we'll use **`ndk-gdb-eclipse`** instead of **`ndk-gdb`**.

### Debugging/Stepping into Code

6. **Step Into the Java Code!**

> - Put a breakpoint in the DebuggingTestActivity.java file at line 20 (System.out.println("hello world!")).
> - Insert a breakpoint in your main Activity BEFORE any calls into native code are made.  onCreate() is generally the best place for this.
> - Start the DebuggingTest application in Debug mode by clicking on the little arrow next to the bug and selecting "DebuggingTest Java Debug".
> - You'll see a pop-up on the screen labeled "Confirm Perspective Switch". Press "Yes" if you'd like it to switch to your Debug Perspective. I would recommend doing so.
> - At this point, you should have hit the breakpoint you set.

**Warning:** The breakpoint we just hit sits inside of the `onCreate` function. This function will be called AFTER all static `loadLibrary` calls have been made. Notice that outside of the onCreate function there is a `System.loadLibrary("DebuggingTestJNI")` inside of a static block. This loadLibrary call will execute before we enter our `onCreate` function, ensuring that our native symbols are loaded by the time we hit our initial breakpoint. It is imperative that we are stopped at a breakpoint before proceeding!

7. **Step Into the C/C++ Code!**

> - In your Terminal, navigate to the DebuggingTest directory and type the following command:
>   `ndk-gdb-eclipse` ← **Remember that we created this file back in step 6**
> - If successful, the command should complete without any response.
> - Go back to Eclipse and run your C/C++ debugger by clicking the little arrow next to the bug and selecting "DebuggingTest C and CPP Debug"
> - **Note:** When I do this, I see dozens of errors in my Eclipse console, but things still seem to be working…
> - Switch back to your Java Perspective.
> - Click the double arrows at the top right of right of your Eclipse window and select Java.
> - Open DebuggingTest/jni/com_sample_test_DebuggingTestActivity.cpp
> - Set a breakpoint in the first JNI function that will be called by your main Activity.
> - Click Run → Resume (<kbd>F8</kbd>)
> - You'll get the Perspective Switch message again, so feel free to switch back to the Debug Perspective.

You should have just hit the breakpoint we just set in the native code!

Congratulations!!!

At this point you should be able to take what you've learned and adapt it to existing projects you may have.

Comment: awesome! This works beautifully. A little tedious, but at the moment I don't have time to try and figure out why my project can't debug using the ndk way of debugging. You've saved me a bunch of hours.

Comment: Just a note though, I am using the ndk-r9d and combine with Eclipse (Mars Release (4.5.0)) setting the variable in the manifest: Debuggable=true is a syntax error. I don't know how to get around this though.