# Not able to debug Native Application in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to learn native application development in Android and for that i created a sample application and now i am trying to debug it. I followed tutorial on this [page](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/) for debugging. But now when i start debugging using this configuration i get the following error:

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
```

My development Environment (if needed):

```
  GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
  Eclipse - the eclipse ADT bundle downloaded from the android developers website
  ADT package version 23.0.1.1259578
  Eclipse CDT - Eclipse c/c++ Development Tools - 8.1.2.201302132326
  Eclipse CDT - GDB Common - 7.0.0.201302132326
  NDK - android-ndk-r10c-linux-x86_64
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug native code in Android Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638849/debug-native-code-in-android-library) and [How to debug native code in an Android library project?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15798738/608639)

Comment: Also, consider [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159644/debug-native-application-on-samsung-4-4-2-package-is-unknown-with-run-as-comma) Some regression was introduced with respect to file permissions in Android 4.3 (patched in Android 4.4). Samsung still seems to experience problems.
Make sure you are not in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

use debug-able permission like this:

```
 <application

       android:debuggable="true"
        >
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: you can't do this because when you do this it gives a error saying: `Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one`

Comment: Oh really. Have you find out the application tag in manifest if found then paste this line in it Otherwise leave the solution.But don't say  you can't do this .Already tested solution.

Comment: well i too tried it and i wasn't able to add it. And AFIK during development the debuggable property is set to true be default.

Comment: the debuggable property need to be set to true manually for the ndk build options to be automatically changed. you can deactivate the specific lint check from within eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986724/can-not-set-debuggable-flag-in-androidmanifest-xml

Answer (score 0):

Enable debugging by this command
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_OPTIM=debug. Hard coding is not allowed on android.mk file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to debug the code by following the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987279/is-this-tutorial-wrong). I am not posting the steps i followed because i do not want to duplicate the answer. If someone faces a problem following the answer given in the link provided, I will be more than happy to help.