# How to run my developed android application in my active android device from eclipse?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am developing android application. I want to test my application in active android device from eclipse.

My device is Huawei Honor Holly.

I enabled "USB debugging" mode in my device.

I installed "Google USB Driver" in SDK manager.

I was trying to modify "android:debuggable="true"" in AndroidManifest.xml. It shows error like "Android Error :Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one"

Help me out to solve this problem

Comment: first of all move beyond eclipse and switch to android studio asap. and secondly why do you mean by "leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one""

Comment: why you want to hardcode "android:debuggable="true"?

Comment: I got that suggestion from someone in StackOverflow

Comment: You don't need to set debluggable, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986724/can-not-set-debuggable-flag-in-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar When you give this kind of advice not related to the question, give some arguments. Because perhaps he can't change his IDE simply.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin i gave the suggestion because google has stopped support for eclipse and has introduced its own ide

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar Yes I know :-) But if he works with eclipse in a company, he probably can't change this without good arguments :-)

Comment: check out this link and you will know why https://www.airpair.com/android/android-studio-vs-eclipse

Comment: on a different note, people at SO have become lazy. They tend to ask more before searching SO itself. It's like they are pushing work on others. These kind of questions already have so many answers on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

When I make apps, I compile it to a APK-file and send it to my phone and install it.

OR

I make the apps ON my phone, using:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

If there goes something wrong, I use aLogcat (Needs permissions to read logs (needs root to give permission))

Answer (score 0):

There is a correct adb driver in the phone. Just change the usb connection option to cdrom and then update the driver from phone's virtual cdrom.